# how to pass multiple values to controller of codeigniter by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
function getdata(x,y)
{

    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

        if(xmlhttp.readystate==4) {
            document.getElementByID("txt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","base_url()/vendor/home/getdata"+x +y,true);

    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

I am passing two values `x,y` to the function from a view. Then I want to pass it to controller as in the program. But `y` is concantenated to `x`. If I use `,` or `&` operator, it is not passing values to controller. Which operator should I use to pass both values `x` and `y` to controller?

Comment: In your controller, show us how you're accessing the parameters you're sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add them as additional segments to the URI:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","base_url()/vendor/home/getdata/"+x +"/" +y,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`xmlhttp.open("GET","base_url()/vendor/home/getdata/"+x+"/"+y,true);`

Make sure your codeigniter getdata method is like this :-

`function getdata ($x = '', $y = '') {}`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
var url = "<?php echo base_url('vendor/home/getdata');?>"+"/?x="+x+"&y="+y;

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
```